# Subsetting a Dataframe by Column Contents in Separate DataFrame - Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, subset

How do I subset a dataframe with the contents of another dataframes column?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"0": ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], "Index": [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"0": ['two', 'two', 'three', 'three']})

a = [i for i in df1['0'] if i in df2['0']]
```

Results

```
print(a)    
[]
```

Desired output:
print(a)

```
       0        index
0      two      2
1      three    3
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2).drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: What do you want to do ?  Keep the rows from df1 that have the same "0" than df2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep keep this strange unnecessary list comprehension, you need to pass `s.values`:

```
>>> [i for i in df1['0'].values if i in df2['0'].values]
['two', 'three']
```

But to get directly that your input implies you want, just select entries in `df1` where the `0` column value is in `df2`'s `0` column values:

```
>>> df1[df1['0'].isin(df2['0'])]
       0  Index
1    two      2
2  three      3
```

And you can reset the indices too, invoke `df_name.reset_index(drop=True)`.